# Typescript неверно определяет тип возвращаемого значения функции

Tags: javascript, typescript

Всем доброго времени суток!)

Версия TS - 2.9.1

Суть проблемы: есть type:

```
export type IReducer<T> = (state: T, action: IAction) => T;
```

Есть функция:

```
export interface IStateCommon {
    data: boolean;
}

export const defaultStateCommon = {
    data: false,
};

export const reducerCommon: IReducer<IStateCommon> = (state = 
defaultStateCommon, { type, payload }) => {
    switch (type) {
        case constantCommonTestFormSubmit:
            return {
                data: payload.data,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

При попытке вернуть объект с левым ключом (another) ошибки не возникает:

```
export const reducerCommon: IReducer<IStateCommon> = (state = 
defaultStateCommon, { type, payload }) => {
    switch (type) {
        case constantCommonTestFormSubmit:
            return {
                another: 123,
                data: payload.data,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Если принудительно указать тип возвращаемого значения (хотя он и так указан в type) ошибка все таки возникает:

```
export const reducerCommon: IReducer<IStateCommon> = (state = 
defaultStateCommon, { type, payload }): IStateCommon => {
    switch (type) {
        case constantCommonTestFormSubmit:
            return {
                another: 123,
                data: payload.data,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему так происходит?

Заранее спасибо за ответы :)

Comment: typescript-fsa кстати хорошая библиотека